# Make a class suitable for Property Change Notification

Tags: c#, wpf

To implement data binding in WPF, according to MS a "class needs to provide the proper property changed notifications." [[ref here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)]

AFAIK, part of setting this up means taking the following steps, if not already set up in the class (ref [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#classes) on MSDN):

- When properties are changed, they need call to a method to raise an event.

  - This means auto-implemented properties must be changed so they use a private backing field, so `set` can change the property and also call the method to raise an event.
- The class needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.
- The class needs to declare the PropertyChangedEventHandler event.
- The event needs to be raised in something like this:

...

```
// Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event 
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

If I already have many existing classes that do not take any of these steps, what is the best way to change these classes so they change *only so far as is needed to make them meet these standards*?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why the variable `handler` is needed?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper This is the standard C# pattern (at least prior to C#6) for raising events in a thread safe manner. Eric Lippert explains all [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx).

Comment: To clarify, I know how to implement this manually, but hoping for something more DRY-like.

Comment: @Olly: Interesting, thanks. Never came across that in any of the C# books I read (though all of those were written in the early days of C#).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the minimum-possible-code-impact solution, then you want the [Fody PropertyChanged weaver](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged). This is installed as a NuGet package with `Install-Package PropertyChanged.Fody`, or through the VS package manager dialogue.

Once installed, you can mark a class with the `[ImplementPropertyChanged]` attribute, and your job is basically done. The weaver will add the relevant event calls *at compile time* by manipulating the generated IL, which means that you don't have to explicitly implement the interface or the event calls in code. You can keep your auto-implemented property syntax, too!

The linked docs provide details of more advanced cases but, in my experience, the out-of-box behaviour is sufficient for almost all needs.

Comment: This looks like an excellent option for a case where there is a lot of existing classes. You should mention though that the INPC implementation should be done in a base class that they all derive from.

Comment: No, I shouldn't, because you don't need to use a base class, or even explicitly implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. You just add the attribute and you're done. It's also an excellent option for ground-up projects, because it just removes all of the boilerplate.

Comment: Been there, tried that - and it didnt work  10% of the time. So I ended up just doing it manually. Same with PostSharp.

Comment: In what way did it not work? I've never had any issues using Fody; haven't tried PostSharp.

Comment: So what you are saying is that it will implement it fully and individually on every class that you decorate? If so I would be in two minds about using it - the ease of getting all classes notifiable vs. long term code maintainability and OO correctness.

Answer (score 5):

I love this implementation with [CallerMemberName] in C# 5 as described [here](http://www.ronaldrosier.net/Blog/2014/01/14/improve_inotifypropertychanged_implementation_without_strings)

```
protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
{
    ...
}
```

Just make the parameter optional and decorate it with the CallerMemberName attribute.

Your property now looks like this:

```
public DateTime Time
{
    get { return this.model.DateTime; }
    set
    {
        this.model.DateTime = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a real nice approach, I like it

Comment: One thing to watch for here is that you might not want to fire notifications if the property hasn't actually changed; this can be slightly wasteful in the best case and even lead to stack overflow in the worst case with circular property updates.  I prefer to use a wrapper SetProperty method that takes the field by reference along with `value`, as well as the `[CallerMemberName]` parameter.  It only fires if the value actually changes and returns a bool so you can use the information as to whether it changed to perform other logic in the setter.

Answer (score 1):

i usually like to use this implementation to notify the changes in my properties

```
class IWillNotifyYou : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _firstProperty;
    public int FirstProperty
    {
        get { return _firstProperty; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _firstProperty)
            {
                _firstProperty = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FirstProperty");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _secondProperty;
    public string SecondProperty
    {
        get { return _secondProperty; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _secondProperty)
            {
                _secondProperty = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SecondProperty");
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

note that you could create a specialized event with the name of the property like FirstPropertyChanged

Comment: This is correct, but I'm hoping to do something other than re-write all existing classes manually.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to identify what role your existing classes play now. WPF is most beneficial using MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel). Identifying the role of your current classes will help determine what needs to be changed (if anything).

Assuming your existing classes are Business Objects, it is up to you to decide whether or not you even need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. WPF is easiest to work with by binding to `ViewModel`. The `ViewModel` is what actually handles the data between the `View` (WPF screen) and the `Model`.

The `Model` can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but it does not have to. The `ViewModel` will hold whatever properties are needed for that specific screen (or control) and is probably the path you will want to explore so you do not completely 180* your existing business objects.

Answer (score -1):

Add ": INotifyPropertyChanged" after your class definition:

```
Public class Test : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
}
```

Accept ReSharpers recommendation to implement the interface for this class (you might have to install ReSharper for this to work).

Then, in the setter for any property, add this:

```
OnPropertyChanged("PropertyName")
```

This means that you can now bind properties in the XAML to this property in this class.

Comment: To be on the safe side, though, `OnPropertyChanged` should only be invoked if the property value has really changed. Otherwise, you might run into ugly oscillating infinite loop issues by properties that keep updating each other infinitely by repeatedly assigning the same "new" values again.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of manual typing... any way to do this without refactoring every class and auto-implemented property manually?

Comment: In theory, you could use PostSharp to do this for you automatically, but in practice, you will find that (a) this is the least of your concerns and (b) if you have ReSharper installed, it has lots of features to autocomplete so its usually only a few keystrokes.

Comment: @AaronThomas There are tools that will automatically add it during the compilation process, [PostSharp is one example](https://www.postsharp.net/model/inotifypropertychanged). (The free version only lets you use it on 10 classes per project). Unity is another example but it involves [more manual coding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660851(v=pandp.20).aspx) writing up the interception and you must resolve your objects through Unity.

Comment: Lastly, another pattern is make a `ViewModelBase` class that has the `OnPropertyChanged` and a [`SetProperty`](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4d83ba3a5427c7866ae8) method. Then you just do `SetProperty(ref _propertyName, value);` in the setter.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain I like this pattern, but it also means that you cannot inherit that class from another, which leads to limitations further down the line. Thus, I usually just type the interface name and let ReSharper write the code for me to implement the interface.

Comment: The first place I encountered the SetProperty method was from [Prism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn736263(v=pandp.50).aspx), `BindableBase` is what they call what I was calling `ViewModelBase`. Also if you are using ReSharper you can put `[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]` on `SetProperty` and it will use it for the right click menu's "To property with INotifyPropertyChanged", they added support for the `bool FunctionName(ref object, string)` signature to be compatible with Prism.